# how to delete row in google sheets using api v4 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

```
            var params1 = {
               spreadsheetId: 'Id', 
                range: "sheet 1!A2",
            };
        
            var clearValuesRequestBody = {
            };
        
            var request = await gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.clear(params1, clearValuesRequestBody);
```

I am trying to delete a row in google sheets using google sheets API in javascript. But I am able to delete only the first cell of the row. I believe there has to be something in clear values request body but I don't know what. Also if you can suggest me how to remove that blank row that has been created by deleting this row, that would be great.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the documentation, but I am knew to APIs and stuffs. So, I am not able to follow what to do specifically. Can you please suggest an example code where it has been implemented? I can remove the row from the sheet but I don't know how to remove that blank row from the google sheet. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can basically copy the request listed in the doc into the example for performing batch updates in JS.

```
var batchUpdateRequest = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
  spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
  resource: batchUpdateRequest
})
```

You can check [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) to see how to find the `spreadsheetId` and the `sheetId`. You could put those values in variables or plop them directly into the code where they are referenced.

The `startIndex` and `endIndex` tell it to delete row one. Since it is zero-indexed, `"startIndex":0` refers to the first row, and `"endIndex":1` says to stop before the second row. The `endIndex` is exclusive, meaning the actions will apply to the part starting with the row indicated by `startIndex` and ending just before `endIndex`.

Note: I have not actually used the Google Sheets API. The above information is based solely on what I could find in the docs. [batch update in JS](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#javascript), [deletion API request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#delete_rows_or_columns).